# ValueError: too many values to unpack in Python Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a function that accepts a string, list and a dictionary

```
def superDynaParams(myname, *likes, **relatives): # *n is a list and **n is dictionary
    print '--------------------------'
    print 'my name is ' + myname

    print 'I like the following'

    for like in likes:
        print like

    print 'and my family are'

    for key, role in relatives:
        if parents[role] != None:
             print key + ' ' + role
```

but it returns an error

> ValueError: too many values to unpack

my parameters are

```
superDynaParams('Mark Paul',
                'programming','arts','japanese','literature','music',
                father='papa',mother='mama',sister='neechan',brother='niichan')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['too many values to unpack', iterating over a dict. key=>string, value=>list](//stackoverflow.com/q/5466618/90527)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are looping over a dictionary:

```
for key, role in relatives:
```

but that only yields *keys*, so one single object at a time. If you want to loop over keys and values, use the `dict.items()` method:

```
for key, role in relatives.items():
```

On Python 2, use the `dict.iteritems()` method for efficiency:

```
for key, role in relatives.iteritems():
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an iterator instead to iterate over the items:

```
relatives.iteritems()

for relative in relatives.iteritems():
    //do something
```